# 2 Selects with different WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a solution for a query that gives me 2 columns which get filled from 2 different where clauses .

UNIT TABLE

| timestamp | unit | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31.12.2020 16:15 | UNIT1 | 1 |
| 31.12.2020 17:15 | UNIT1 | 2 |
| 31.12.2020 18:15 | UNIT2 | 1 |
| 31.12.2020 19:15 | UNIT2 | 2 |

and I'm looking for a result like this :

| unit | timestamp1 | timestamp2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Unit1 | 31.12.2020 16:15 | 31.12.2020 17:15 |
| Unit2 | 31.12.2020 18:15 | 31.12.2020 19:15 |

Something like

```
SELECT (SELECT timestamp from Unit WHERE unit_status = '1') ,
       (SELECT timestamp from Unit WHERE unit_status = '2')
FROM Unit
```

But it doesn't link properly, can you help me with this, I'm sure the solution is pretty easy but I don't get there.

Comment: Are you just wanting min(timestamp) and max(timestamp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this should get what you want, I dont think its overall as practical in a final solution.  Will the status always be 1, 2?  will there be different numbers?  will there be gaps between, such as 1, 5?  Also, the basis of the units.  Sometimes you should not be too vague in just asking a question, but help give it context on what you are trying to do.  Regardless, try this...

```
select
      ut1.unit,
      ut1.timestamp  TS1,
      ut2.timestamp  TS2
   from
      UnitTable ut1
         JOIN UnitTable ut2
            on ut1.unit = ut2.unit
            AND ut1.status = ut2.status-1
   where
      ut1.status = 1
```

By self-joining to the same table, different alias, you can use the same table more than once.  By joining on the same UNIT, you are good there.  the AND portion of that join by the status of the first equal to the second status -1  (thus 1 = (2-1) ) is ensuring that the second table is pointing to the status ID = 2 (hence -1).

By applying a WHERE clause for ut1.status = 1, you are only retrieving instances where the first status exists, JOINED to an instance where a second ALSO exists.  If you are interested in all 1 status regardless of the corresponding 2 status, just change it to a LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Again, based on caveats described, it would work, but may not be the best long-term.

Answer (score 2):

```
select unit, max(case when status = 1 then timestamp end) timestamp1
, max(case when status =2  then timestamp end) timestamp2
from table1
group by unit
```